# Refreshing Vuetify V-Calendar with new events hide the events in the "Month" view

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Currently developing an appointment-making application using a C# API in Vue.js with Vuetify, I encounter a behaviour with the component V-Calendar I can't comprehend. When originally feeding events to the calendar (appointments retrieved from a database by contacting the API), those events are correctly displayed as followed :
[Original calendar loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V75X1.png)

The query originally ignores cancelled appointments. However, I give the option to include them with a checkbox in the calendar header. Checking the box automatically refreshes the list of events through a watcher. When doing so, the calendar has a strange behaviour and does no longer display the events. This only occurs in the "Month" view, the "Day" and "Week" ones correctly display the data.
[Result of refreshing the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz4j5.png)

Here is the definition of my calendar (programming in french, translated in english the variables/methods for your easier understanding)

```
<v-calendar ref="calendar"
                        v-model="focus"
                        :event-color="getEventColor"
                        :events="events"
                        :first-interval="13"
                        :interval-count="22"
                        :interval-format="intervalFormat"
                        :interval-minutes="30"
                        :type="type"
                        :weekdays="weekDays"
                        color="primary"
                        event-more-text="Show more"
                        event-overlap-mode="column"
                        locale="fr"
                        @change="updateRange"
                        @click:event="showEvent"
                        @click:more="viewDay"
                        @click:date="viewDay">
              <template #event="event">
                <div v-if="event.eventParsed.input.idEtat === etats.annule"><s><i>{{
                    event.eventParsed.input.name
                  }}</i></s></div>
                <div>{{ event.eventParsed.input.name }}</div>
              </template>
            </v-calendar>
```

The definition of the updateRange method (called once when the page is loaded in the created() hook)

```
async updateRange({start, end}) {
  this.currentDateDebut = start.date;
  this.currentDateFin = end.date;
  await this.refreshCalendarData();
}
```

The definition of the refreshCalendar method

async refreshCalendarData() {
this.loading = true;

```
  const events = []
  //Récupération des rendez-vous
  await this.getRendezVous(this.currentDateDebut, this.currentDateFin);
  this.rendezVous = await this.$store.getters["rendezVous/getRendezVousData"];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rendezVous.length; i++) {
      const calculImcPossible = (this.rendezVous[i].taille != null && this.rendezVous[i].taille > 0) &&
            (this.rendezVous[i].poids != null && this.rendezVous[i].poids > 0);
        const calculImc = calculImcPossible
            ? (Math.round(this.rendezVous[i].poids / ((this.rendezVous[i].taille / 100) * (this.rendezVous[i].taille / 100)) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
            : null;
        const libelleImc = this.getLibelleImc(calculImc);
        events.push({
          id: this.rendezVous[i].id,
          idInstitution: this.rendezVous[i].idInstitution,
          name: this.heureCourte(this.rendezVous[i].date) + " | Appointment",
          start: new Date(this.rendezVous[i].date),
          end: new Date(new Date(this.rendezVous[i].date).getTime() + 15 * 60000),
          color: this.rendezVous[i].institution.color,
          timed: true,
          taille: this.rendezVous[i].taille != null && this.rendezVous[i].taille > 0
              ? this.rendezVous[i].taille + "cm"
              : "indéfinie",
          poids: this.rendezVous[i].poids != null && this.rendezVous[i].poids > 0
              ? this.rendezVous[i].poids + "kg"
              : "indéfini",
          sexe: this.rendezVous[i].patient.sexe,
          imc: calculImc != null ? (calculImc + " (" + libelleImc + ")") : "non-déterminé",
          nom: this.rendezVous[i].patient.nom + " " + this.rendezVous[i].patient.prenom,
          telephone: this.rendezVous[i].patient.telephone != null ? this.rendezVous[i].patient.telephone : "-",
          email: this.rendezVous[i].patient.email != null ? this.rendezVous[i].patient.email : "-",
          commentaire: this.rendezVous[i].commentaire,
          regime: this.rendezVous[i].regime,
          hospitalisation: this.rendezVous[i].hospitalisation,
          contagieux: this.rendezVous[i].contagieux,
          incontinent: this.rendezVous[i].incontinent,
          naissance: this.dateCourte(this.rendezVous[i].patient.naissance),
          diabete: this.rendezVous[i].diabete.type,
          examen: this.rendezVous[i].examen.nom,
          idEtat: this.rendezVous[i].idEtat,
          idPatient: this.rendezVous[i].idPatient,
          typeEvent: "rendez-vous",
          editable: this.rendezVous[i].editable
        });
    }
}
```

And finally, the definition of the watcher showCancalledAppointments

```
async showCancelledAppointments() {
  await this.refreshCalendarData();
}
```

Do you have any idea why this behaviour is displayed by the calendar ? Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the solution with the command 'npm update' fixed the problem. The latest version of Vuetify seems to solve the issue